# lotus notes traveler on android email text body appears VERY small and to left of screen

Tags: email, android, lotus-notes

our company has a helpdesk and they cannot get this worked out. also they claim I am the only complaint of this issue. I have reinstalled lotus notes traveler as requested. it seems its only e mails that originate from laptops or desktops appear this way. the text is so small as to be unreadable, shifted left on the screen and cannot be zoomed. if I forward to my yahoo acct they arrive ok. driving me nuts.

Comment: IBM Notes Traveler is now [IBM Verse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lotus.sync.traveler). IBM Verse replaces Lotus Notes Traveler and will continue to work with your existing Traveler servers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try uninstalling Android System Webview?  I had the same issue regarding really small text. I also was experiencing that the content of the lotus note traveller emails was not displaying when I opened the emails (or disappearing to a blank email body section a millisecond after I opened the email) even though I could see the first line of the email in the snippet in the inbox list.

The only way to view the mails was to click reply, then select Respond Inline. After doing this the mail was displayed in text format and I could read the content.

This issue occurred sporadically over the last weeks. I thought it was an app I had installed but it persisted after I uninstalled almost everything.

Uninstalling the app Android System Webview from the play store  seems to have fixed the problem. It now  shows that I can update the app to the new version but it seeks to be the new version that caused the issue.